# How does daylight saving work in php (difference between php and hhvm)?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dst, hhvm

I need to detect when a timestamp is in daylight saving or not.

I'm using this code to test the functionality:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

$timestamp = $baseTimestamp = 1509234900; // Sunday, 29 October of 2017 1:55:00 GMT+02:00 DST
$date = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($baseTimestamp);

echo "DateTime\t\t| Is in summer \t| Minutes passed\n";

for($i = 0; $i < 70; $i++) {
    $date = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s \t|I") . "\t\t| " . ($timestamp - $baseTimestamp)/60 . "\n";
    $timestamp = $timestamp + 60;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/dqNlK

Working with *Europe/Berlin*, I've seen that in March, when at 2.00 we pass from winter to summer, php solves it right, but then in October, when it is supposed to come back from summer to winter at 3.00, it doesn't work as expected.

In this case, we have two timestamps corresponding to the same hour (at 3 is 2 again), but the timestamp is unique, so for 2.00 there must be one timestamp in the summer time and another one in the winter time.

Using hhvm, it shows the right value, but normal php interpreters show that is not in summer for both 2.00 (the first one, which is 2am and the second one which is when at 3am is 2am again. This is the one that should say is not in summer anymore)

Comment: ... that actually looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes, I think it is. Try this:
    echo (new DateTime)->setTimestamp(1509235200)->getTimestamp();
And you will see that it outputs a different timestamp. HHVM doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several long-lived, unresolved, DST-related bugs in PHP.

You appear to have hit on this one:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68549

Answer (score 0):

```
function isSummer($timestamp) {
    $date = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($timestamp);

    if ($date->format('I') == 1) {
        return true;
    }

   return ($date->getTimestamp() > $timestamp);
}
```

I think this is going to do the trick

Comment: This only will work if timestamp has never passed through a DateTime object